# Using NSBezierPath draw only border of star

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Using `NSBezierPath` draw Star with only outer surfaces. Below code is draw star that intersect all lines.

```
- (NSBezierPath *) getPathForStar{

    CGRect rect =self.frame;
    NSBezierPath * path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

    [path setLineWidth:2.0];
    CGFloat xCenter = rect.size.width / 2;
    CGFloat yCenter = rect.size.height / 2;

    float width;
    if(rect.size.width > rect.size.height) {
        width = rect.size.height;
    } else {
        width = rect.size.width;
    }
    double r = width / 2.0;
    float flip = -1.0;

    double theta = 2.0 * M_PI * (2.0 / 5.0); // 144 degrees

    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(xCenter, r*flip+yCenter)];

    for (NSUInteger k=1; k<5; k++)
    {
        float x = r * sin(k * theta);
        float y = r * cos(k * theta);
        [path lineToPoint:CGPointMake( x+xCenter, y*flip+yCenter)];
    }

     return path;
}
```

I would like to draw only border of star. Thanks.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/w46Mr5Vm ? How do debug your error? `for (NSUInteger k=1; k<5; k++)` Instead of 5, check what's drawn if it's 1, 2, then 3, then 4, then 5. You'll see that you need to add intermediary steps.

Comment: How are you currently drawing the path? This code only creates it.

Comment: What part of the code isn't understood? If there are 5 calls to -lineToPoint:, then ya you'll have 5 lines. If you want the border of a 5 pointed star, you'll need 10 lines to be drawn (2 for each pointed segment). Is the math just not understood?

Comment: i am currently used NSBezierPath stroke method to draw the star.